# IF function not working with concatenate

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation

I have an if function that compares two values.

```
=IF(INDIRECT(NextSheetName()&"!A1")&INDIRECT(NextSheetName()&"!B1") = A1&B1, Yes, No)
```

The first part:

```
INDIRECT(NextSheetName()&"!A1")&INDIRECT(NextSheetName()&"!B1")
```

runs flawlessly on its own but it does not work when contained within the `IF` statement. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `Yes` and `No` defined in the worksheet? For me it works if I change to `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Comment: And what is the error message? `#NAME?`?

Comment: Yes #NAME? is the error.  And your right it works fine.  My mistake I forgot to define Yes and No or put quotes around them.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Changed to TRUE and FALSE instead of Yes and No.  Works great!